# Where to store orders for non-registered users on e-commerce site?

Tags: sql, database-design, e-commerce

We are trying to add new features to our e-commerce project and currently struggling with no-register option.

We are currently storing general user data in `users` table (username,birthdate, etc) and it has relations with `user_addresses` (delivery address, telephone, ..), `user_orders` (invoice total, date, ..), `user_order_items` (which products bought at what price) tables. Admin panels use these tables to track orders.

What is the best way to implement no-register option? We thought registering users with random passwords with their given name and e-mail address. But this would be an obstacle if user wants to register next time because e-mail address will be already registered. What do you recommend?

Comment: Before ordering: store basket in session. After order save in database. But before unregistered user can be able to send order he/she should have verification. You can do this by sending email with request of confirmation.

Comment: But that makes no difference?

Comment: It does. There will be no object in users table (email You can store in order). If User was not registered You cannot store his/her data in DB.

Comment: But the whole point is saving user some time. It won't happen if user goes through some validation process.

Comment: Validation process is strongly recomended, or you can be flooded.

Answer (score 4):

You have 3 ooptions:

1) Each order requires registered and authenticated user

2) Order does not requires user to be registered/authenticated. 
In this case You have to protect Yourself against beeing flooded by bots and users. 
So You can:

1. add captcha (against bots)
2. add email confirmation (for verification) - order will be saved in DB only after clicking in special link in mail.
3. veryfiy each order by the phone
4. you can send orders from non registered users just for mail instead store them in DB (not prefered)

Address, contact, and other information You can hold in oder table (for registered users they will be empty)

3) 4) You can mix this options together.

Remember that user should have benefit for registration (for instance: Orders history), other way nobody will register. They will use simpliest way of ordering.

[image]

Comment: how do you track addresses or know where to ship without storing addresses for non-registered users? (nice answer btw)

Comment: in us_temporary_user table

Answer (score 2):

The main difference between registered and non-registered users is usually that the former can log in and see their orders whereas the latter can't.

So you can store them just alike, only that you need a pseudo name and no password for non-registered users. That is to say: 1. make the password nullable in your table, 2. create a UUID for the user name whenever someone orders without registering.

(Maybe you will have to make more fields nullable that are obligatory for registered users but not for non-registered ones.)

EDIT: Of course you can also keep the password not nullable and generate some password along with the user name that will never be used.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to use the email address as the user name? an email addresses is unique, and its not an extra detail for the customer to remember.

then if a registered customer has forgotten or wants to change their password - you send them an email to complete the process. For a customer that has not registered - in essence its exactly the same as forgetting the password. They can be sent an email and set a password.

otherwise you would not let someone log in with a blank password - so having that field be blank is not going to be an issue.